# How to find my own mobile number on Huawei P30 Pro?

Tags: huawei

Is there any way to find the number of my SIMs? I tried to find it on the "about" page of the phone, but it's not there.

Any suggestion?

Android version = 9

Comment: I don't think there's a way [if the SIM card doesn't store its phone number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6797278/2821954). Contact your provider's support instead.

Answer (score 0):

Huawei P30 EMUI 11:
Settings → Mobile Network → SIM menagement.
Here you will see a list of your SIM cards and their phone numbers.